# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch shows horizontal scroll bar

Tags: touch, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have used "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" to have smooth swipe across the screen for mobile (IOS Device).My page have 5 list items and need to swipe smoothly.After  added class "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch"  Can see a horizontal scroll bar which goes away after I complete my swipe or remove hand from device.

I have tried using overflow-y hidden  but this doesn't help

How to disable this horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="nav-tablist">
<ul class="nav-listitems" id="tab-controls" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item active" >
<a href="" class="navtab-link active" id="Home" aria-controls="tabs_Home" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">Home     </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" >
<a href="" class="navtab-link " id="aboutus" aria-controls="tabs_aboutus" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">aboutus                                         
</a>                                    
</li>
<li class="nav-item" >
<a href="" class="navtab-link " id="help" aria-controls="tabs_help" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false">help         </a>                                   
 </li>
<li class="nav-item" >
<a href="" class="navtab-link " id="contact" aria-controls="tabs_contact" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false"> Stores                                        
</a>                                    
</li>
<li class="nav-line" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 48px; left: 0px;"></li></ul>
</div>

Here is my code ....
```